# Youtube API v3 error - Hangs on await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

Tags: winforms

I've been playing around with the Youtube V3 API and i can't seem to get it to work in a windows form. I got the sample code to work, so I know that my API key works correctly, but when i try to convert it from a console app, the code hangs on this line,

`var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();`

I haven't been able to find anything relevant to this issue, there are no compile errors or run-time errors are being thrown.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

namespace MiddleManYTDL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("YouTube Data API: Search");

            try
            {
                new Form1().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException exs)
            {
                foreach (var ex in exs.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }      

        private async Task Run()
        {
          var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
          {
              ApiKey = "My API Key",
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
          });

          var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
          searchListRequest.Q = "Google"; // Replace with your search term.
          searchListRequest.MaxResults = 10;

          MessageBox.Show("This will Display");
          // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
          var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
          MessageBox.Show("This never gets executed");

          List<string> videos = new List<string>();
          List<string> channels = new List<string>();
          List<string> playlists = new List<string>();
          // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
          // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
          foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
          {
            switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
            {
              case "youtube#video":
                videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title,       
                  searchResult.Id.VideoId));
                break;

              case "youtube#channel":
                channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, 
                 searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
               break;

              case "youtube#playlist":
                playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, 
                 searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                break;
            }
          }
          MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Videos:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", videos)));
          MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channels:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", channels)));
          MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Playlists:\n{0}\n", string.Join("\n", playlists)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the YouTube API as such. Your problem is in the blocking `Wait()` call on the following line:

```
new Form1().Run().Wait();
```

What is happening is your code gets to `Run()` and executes the part of the method up to the `await` keyword synchronously (in your case - on the UI thread). Then, while the `await` is in progress, the execution returns to your `Form.Load` handler, which immediately hits the `Wait()` call and blocks the UI thread until the task returned by `Run()` has completed. At some point after that your `await`ed task inside `Run()` finishes and the async state machine attempts to execute the rest of the `Run()` method on the UI thread. Now you have `Wait()` blocking the UI thread while it's waiting for `Run()` to complete and `Run()` waiting for the UI thread to become available so that the remainder of the `async` method can be executed. Neither can make any progress. This deadlock scenario is very common whenever `async/await` methods are mixed with the blocking `Wait()` or `Result` calls.

There are two possible fixes:

- Use `async/await` all the way (i.e. no blocking `Wait()` and `Result` calls up in the call hierarchy)
- Rewrite your `Run()` method so that no UI elements are accessed after the `await`, and use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to prevent `await` from capturing, and subsequently posting back to the synchronization context installed on your UI thread (meaning that the part of your method following the `await` will execute on a thread pool thread).

Personally I'd go with option #1:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("YouTube Data API: Search");

    try
    {
        await new Form1().Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception dispatch is different with async/await,
        // so you don't get the AggregateException - rather
        // just the first exception which caused the task
        // to fault.
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here are some excellent blog posts which discuss the issue you are observing in detail:

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx