# Youtube /v3/search API not returning results in .NET

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is my first shot at using the YouTube v3 search api, so I have a few questions and some code to look at.

My basic issue at this point is that I am working with the sample code provided by Google and I am not getting any results back.  The app hangs on:

```
// Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

Here is my sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

using CPCommon;

namespace CPDataLayer
{
    public class YouTubeSearch : DataLayerBase
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// YouTube Data API v3 sample: search by keyword.
        /// Relies on the Google APIs Client Library for .NET, v1.7.0 or higher.
        /// See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started
        ///
        /// Set ApiKey to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps tab of
        ///   https://cloud.google.com/console
        /// Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
        /// </summary>
        public void TakedownTargetSearch()
        {
            try
            {
                Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                // I x'ed out our api key.
                ApiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = "RSSB"; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 5;
            searchListRequest.ChannelId = "UCaxt22KHbK-AoPJCfXU034g";


            // Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
            var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            List<string> videos = new List<string>();
            List<string> channels = new List<string>();
            List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

            // Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
            // matching videos, channels, and playlists.
            foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
            {
                switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
                {
                    case "youtube#video":
                        videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
                        break;

                    case "youtube#channel":
                        channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                        break;

                    case "youtube#playlist":
                        playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to sign up on the Google Cloud Platform and did get my API key as well as register the YouTube API v3 search API and I can see in the Metrics APIs page that I have called my method 3 times.  So, Google is receiving my calls, but I am not getting anything back.  It is probably something on my end and I'm hoping that it would be easy to spot.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One hundred dollars question: who is running `TakedownTargetSearch`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26880004/8327971) quite nice explanation. Otherwise, why don't you print out those `List<string>` objects?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I needed to make my upstream methods async.  Hadn't worked with async methods before and was confused.  The link helped very much.

Comment: Then you may post a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) too. Other SO users may well find that quite useful.